# Load calendar data to FullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, symfony

I'm using FullCalendar in my Symfony project and I want to load events from database and show them in calendar for user. 
According to documentation I have create a AJAX request to server on my `calendar.html.twig` page and store response in localStorage. This is what I done:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var events = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ path('property.get.reservations') }}',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'propertyId': {{ propertyId }}
        }, success: function (data) {
            console.log('running script within calendar.html.twig')
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                var event = JSON.stringify(value);
                events.push(event);
            });
            localStorage.setItem('events', events);
        }
    });
});
```

Next I'm trying to use this storaged data in my `calnedarService.js` in this way:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: false,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    editable: true,
    events: localStorage.getItem('events'), 
    /* another code */
```

I get an error in the console:

> No route found for "GET /admin/property/edit/1/%7B%22id%22:1,%22start%22:%222016-12-04T00:00:00.000Z%22,%22end%22:%222016-12-07T00:00:00.000Z%22%7D" (from "my_host")

So, for the reasons which I don't know,fullCalendar try to generate route, using parameters, getting from AJAX.

Any help will appreciated

Comment: The error seems unrelated to the code you posted as you're making a POST request, yet the error is referring to a GET

Comment: that's why I posted my question here - script do not must to make any request - it just must to read data from localStorage

Comment: I have solve my problem using Twig variable instead of ajax-requests, but if someone know how to load events before rendering calendar - let me know please :)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, just put this for url :

```
'admin/property/edit/'
```

with the id var at the end of the url